# How to get a string input from a user in a char* in VC++?

Tags: c, visual-c++

I want to take a string as user input in my program....

```
...
char* name;
...
printf("\n\tEnter a string : ");
fflush(stdin);
//gets(name);
//gets_s(name,100);
//fgets(name,100,stdin);
...
```

All the three ways of getting a string input are giving errors.Yes I can take a char array but my requirement is that **input string could be of any length**. How can I get my requirement fulfilled.

The 100 in gets_s/fgets is just to see whether these functions also complain or not.

I am using VS2010.

EDIT: I added visual c++ tag to show that I am using VC++ but my program is in C.

Thanks

Comment: fflush(stdin) is not allowed in C or C++.

Comment: `fgets(&name,100,stdin)`, but you can't and shouldn't try to read further than the length `name` is allocated for.

Comment: I am bit confused, you are using C or C++?

Comment: @Neil:fflush(FILE*) is a part of the Visual C runtime library.Check MSDN.

Comment: @ryanlancer It is defined in both the C and C++ standards only for output streams.

Comment: @Neil:check out the example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: @ryanlancer It doesn't matter what that says.

Comment: @Neil so you mean to say that information on msdn is not 100% correct.

Comment: @ryanlancer In the msdn example: "fflush on input stream is an extension to the C standard" @Neil means that fflush(stdin) is not allowed in C or C++. It doesn't matter if the Visual C runtime allows it. The language does not.

Comment: @Thiago,Neil:So what should I use to clear stdin, because if I do not use fflush(stdin) the program skips the input for string(because program takes several inputs before this string).Also I have used fflush(stdin) in Turbo C/C++ several years ago.

Comment: MSDN not 100% accurate? Of course it isn't!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`In C`, there is no way if you want to handle **"input string that could be of any length"**. You have to allocate enough memory to store the input; that is you have to specify maximum input characters your program wants to handle.

If you want to handle **"input string that could be of any length"**, you can use `C++` `std::string`, for example:

```
std::string stringOfAnyLength;
getline(std::cin,stringOfAnyLength); //read user line input (can be of any length)
```

And your example program is wrong, you should allocate enough buffer by a call to `malloc` first before you use `name` to get user input:

```
char* name;

name=malloc((MAX_LEN+1)*sizeof(Char));
...
printf("\n\tEnter a string : ");
fgets(name,MAX_LEN,stdin);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::string name; std::cin>>name;`. C++ has much better string handling using `std::string` than fiddling with `char*`.